# View is not included during views_pre_execute

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-views

In my Drupal 7 website I created a page consisting of several views. When I use the `hook_views_query_alter-function` (in the *[modulename].views.inc-page*), all the included views can be listed. But when I'm using the `hook_views_pre_execute-function`, 1 specific view is not listed and I can't seem to find out why this is happening.

If anyone can help me?
Kind regards.

Comment: have you tried clearing the cache?

Comment: Looks like it was a problem caused by the view settings in one of my custom module. Thank you for the help thought!